# How to group the List of Lists by their Name in Java

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections, grouping

Suppose I have a class

```
class X {
    String name;
    int value; 
}
```

and I am given multiple `ArrayList`s of these objects, as an example;

```
[{A,2}, {B,1}, {C,3}]
[{C,5}, {D,1}]
[{A,3}, {D,1}]
```

Now I want to merge the list with objects having same name and sum the values so that final output look like

```
[{A,5}, {B,1}, {C,8}, {D,2}]
```

This problem I solved using `HashMap`s (which is not requirement), I want to know if it is possible to merge the lists using list operations and get addition done on the field of the object and show output in `ArrayList` itself?

Comment: is it lists of list ?

Comment: @Ravi no its ArrayList

Comment: ArrayList is also List. right ? My question is whether your data is Lists of List ?

Comment: @Ravi, sorry for confusion, I mean its an ArrayList of Objects. Objects having 2 fields - name and value.

Comment: `[{A,2}, {B,1}, {C,3}], [{C,5}, {D,1}] and [{A,3}, {D,1}]` this is `List<List<Object>>` in your case as pointed out by @Ravi

Comment: Okay yes correct, its lists of list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend ArrayList to build the merge capability.

```
package com.test;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyArrayList<P> extends ArrayList<Pair> {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Pair p1 = new Pair ("A", 2);
       Pair p2 = new Pair ("B", 4);
       Pair p3 = new Pair ("C", 1);

       MyArrayList<Pair> l1 = new MyArrayList<Pair>();
       l1.add(p1);
       l1.add(p2);
       l1.add(p3);

       Pair p4 = new Pair ("A", 5);
       Pair p5 = new Pair ("C", 10);
       Pair p6 = new Pair ("D", 12);

       ArrayList<Pair> l2 = new ArrayList<Pair>();
       l2.add(p4);
       l2.add(p5);
       l2.add(p6);

       l1.merge(l2);
       System.out.println(l1.toJson());

    }

   @Override
   public boolean add(Pair e) {
       Pair p = this.getPair(e);
       if (p == null) return super.add(e);
       p.value += e.value;
       return true;
   }

   public void merge (ArrayList<Pair> list) {
       for(Pair p : list) this.add(p);
   }

   public String toJson() {
       StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer("[");
       for(Pair p : this) s.append("{\"name\":").append("\"").append(p.name).append("\",").append("\"value\":").append(p.value).append("},");
       return s.append("]").deleteCharAt(s.length()-2).toString();
   }

   private Pair getPair (Pair e) {
       for(Pair p : this) if (p.name.equals(e.name)) return p;
       return null;
   }
}
```

Pair Class

```
package com.test;
public class Pair {
   String name;
   int value;
   public Pair(String name, int value) {
      super();
      this.name = name;
      this.value = value;
   }
}
```

Here is the output

```
[{"name":"A","value":7},{"name":"B","value":4},{"name":"C","value":11},{"name":"D","value":12}]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you have any suggestion on converting that json to the format of arraylist for printing. I really appreciate your answer.

Comment: the object 'l1' is already an ArrayList. I fixed the toJson() to convert to string with correct array format. Is that what you are asking for? Let me know.

Comment: @Harry_pb hope you saw my comment above 

Answer (score 0):

You could use **[`stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)** API, which available after JDK 8+.

As part of below given solution, first I'm merging all sub-list into one where `main` is the `List`, which contains `List` of Lists

```
  main.stream()
      .flatMap(List::stream)
      .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Now, it will be easy to **[`groupingby`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-)** them by `Name` and count their values, which will return a `Map`

```
.stream()
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(w -> w.getName(), Collectors.summingInt(w -> w.getValue())))
```

Now, combine all code together

```
    //create dummy List
    List<xyz> last = new ArrayList<>();

    //merge all list into one and they apply group by to sum
    Map<String, Integer> map = main.stream()
                                   .flatMap(List::stream)
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList())
                                   .stream()
                                   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(w -> w.getName(), Collectors.summingInt(w -> w.getValue())));
```

Since, your final output is as `List`. So, we traverse though the map and add it to the `List`.

```
    //add into dummy List
    map.entrySet().stream().forEach((e) -> {
        last.add(new xyz(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
    });
```

I would appreciate any suggestion and/or refinement(s).

Comment: Does this answer your question @Harry_pb . feedback is always appreciated :)

Comment: @Harry_pb did you missed my post :P